# Facebook login: Nothing happens

Tags: android

I´m trying to attach facebook login to my app and when I click on the facebook login button, the app shows "Loading..." and then close.

I already verified the hashes. If i dont inform the hashes then a message appears informing. If i inform a wrong hash, another message is showed informing that the hashes are diferents. So, i presume that the hash is ok.

- My device is a Samsung S4 with android 5.
- Nothing different appear on logcat.
- Facebook SDK is 4.8.2
- My Activity is extending ActionBarActivity
- I already verified that on AndroidManifest my LoginActivity does not
  have noHistory tag.
- Im using Android studio.

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: did you add facebook_id in AndroidManifest ? as Meta tag

Comment: Have you implemented the onActivityResult() as described here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I already use this permitions:


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />